# Error installing PayPalRESTSDK on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm trying to install the paypalrestsdk on a Raspberry Pi but I'm getting a huge error list:

```
$ pip install paypalrestsdk
Collecting paypalrestsdk
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:315: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.
  SNIMissingWarning
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:120: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Using cached paypalrestsdk-1.11.5.tar.gz
Collecting requests>=1.0.0 (from paypalrestsdk)
  Using cached requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting six>=1.0.0 (from paypalrestsdk)
  Using cached six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyopenssl>=0.15 (from paypalrestsdk)
  Using cached pyOpenSSL-0.15.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting cryptography>=0.7 (from pyopenssl>=0.15->paypalrestsdk)
  Using cached cryptography-1.2.3.tar.gz
Collecting idna>=2.0 (from cryptography>=0.7->pyopenssl>=0.15->paypalrestsdk)
  Using cached idna-2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyasn1>=0.1.8 (from cryptography>=0.7->pyopenssl>=0.15->paypalrestsdk)
  Using cached pyasn1-0.1.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting setuptools>=1.0 (from cryptography>=0.7->pyopenssl>=0.15->paypalrestsdk)
  Using cached setuptools-20.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting enum34 (from cryptography>=0.7->pyopenssl>=0.15->paypalrestsdk)
  Using cached enum34-1.1.2.tar.gz
Collecting ipaddress (from cryptography>=0.7->pyopenssl>=0.15->paypalrestsdk)
  Using cached ipaddress-1.0.16-py27-none-any.whl
Collecting cffi>=1.4.1 (from cryptography>=0.7->pyopenssl>=0.15->paypalrestsdk)
  Using cached cffi-1.5.2.tar.gz
Collecting pycparser (from cffi>=1.4.1->cryptography>=0.7->pyopenssl>=0.15->paypalrestsdk)
  Using cached pycparser-2.14.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: paypalrestsdk, cryptography, enum34, cffi, pycparser
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for paypalrestsdk ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-QDhj0w/paypalrestsdk/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpUHqkenpip-wheel- --python-tag cp27:
  usage: -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
     or: -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
     or: -c --help-commands
     or: -c cmd --help

  error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for paypalrestsdk
  Running setup.py clean for paypalrestsdk
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for cryptography ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-QDhj0w/cryptography/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpI47_Acpip-wheel- --python-tag cp27:

  Installed /tmp/pip-build-QDhj0w/cryptography/cffi-1.5.2-py2.7-linux-armv7l.egg
  Searching for pycparser
  Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pycparser/
  Best match: pycparser 2.14
  Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pycparser/pycparser-2.14.tar.gz#md5=a2bc8d28c923b4fe2b2c3b4b51a4f935
  Processing pycparser-2.14.tar.gz
  Running pycparser-2.14/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-jMojU6/pycparser-2.14/egg-dist-tmp-ZE49md
  warning: no previously-included files matching 'yacctab.*' found under directory 'tests'
  warning: no previously-included files matching 'lextab.*' found under directory 'tests'
  warning: no previously-included files matching 'yacctab.*' found under directory 'examples'
  warning: no previously-included files matching 'lextab.*' found under directory 'examples'
  zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...

  Installed /tmp/pip-build-QDhj0w/cryptography/pycparser-2.14-py2.7.egg
  usage: -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
     or: -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
     or: -c --help-commands
     or: -c cmd --help

  error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for cryptography
  Running setup.py clean for cryptography
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for enum34 ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-QDhj0w/enum34/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpt43mirpip-wheel- --python-tag cp27:
  usage: -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
     or: -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
     or: -c --help-commands
     or: -c cmd --help

  error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for enum34
  Running setup.py clean for enum34
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for cffi ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-QDhj0w/cffi/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmp0x88PWpip-wheel- --python-tag cp27:
  usage: -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
     or: -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
     or: -c --help-commands
     or: -c cmd --help

  error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
```

This continues for a while so I've withheld the later bits.

Will paypalrestsdk run on a raspberry pi and what do I need to do to facilitate it?

Comment: `bdist_wheel` requires setuptools >= 0.8.0.  Try `pip install --upgrade pip` then try again.

Comment: When I run `pip install --upgrade pip` I get the response: `Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`.  Running  `$ pip -V` gives me `pip 8.1.0 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Cdarke has identified the issue correctly above but upgrading the Rapsberry Pi to 2.7.11 took some time.  [Here is a good tutorial](https://sowingseasons.com/blog/software/2016/02/building-python-2-7-10-on-raspberry-pi-2/10635877)